# Multiple database with the different (database) structure asp.net mvc

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 with multiple existing database using Entity Framework 6.

The structure is almost the same in each one, except in some case there could be an additional column in a table

Example:

- Database_A has table Table_A with Col_1 and Col_2.
- Database_B has a newer version of data base structure and has Table_A with Col_1, Col_2 and Col_3

I know how to switch from one database to another but my problem is: How I can make my model that covers both (or more) databases structure?

Comment: Are you using an object-relational mapper such as Entity Framework?

Comment: I don't understand what to “make my model that covers both (or more) databases structure” means. Are you trying to do something with this data? What do you want to do if “there could be an additional column”? You tagged your question C# and ASP.NET MVC 5 but I don't see anything about that in your question.

Comment: The first question you need to ask:  What does the product/application owner say should happen in this scenario?  Should it even allow you to proceed if there's a version mismatch between the code and database?  If so, how many different versions do you need to support?

Comment: @tonyapolis Yes i am using entity framework, sorry i didnt mentioned that in question

Comment: @DourHighArch Definatley i am doing Something (Which Is Alot) with data. Why would one want to do through all headache and not doing any thing with it?

Comment: @Taegost Its like , think of a report like Report_A, if there is an extra column Report_A should display that column and if there is No Extra column Report_A (or Whatever) should not display it

Comment: Generally, there should only be one "model" that represents the problem domain... this is often referred to as the domain model. The database(s) is/are merely a mechanism(s) for storing information about the problem domain. A domain model is independent of any persistence mechanism. An "object" in your domain model could be represented by a class that you would then populate with data from a database. With this approach you would need some kind of helper or service to map the class and the entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity framework and are writing code that only deals with the columns common to both databases you should have no problem.  When you create your db context, just pass it the connection string for the appropriate database and the code should work fine.

Gotchas to be aware of:
1. Creating new records where Col_3 is required.  Make sure to have a default value.
2. Using migrations so Entity Framework will try to keep the database matching the model.